# Matching multiple keywords in a text (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, match, matching, keyword-search

Here is my code:

```
// Matching multiple keywords in a text
// Case 1
var text = "Hello, My name is @Steve, I love @Bill, happy new year!";
var keywords = ["steve"];
var matching = text.toLowerCase().search([keywords]);
console.log(matching);
// return 19

// Case 2
var text = "Hello, My name is @Steve, I love @Bill, happy new year!";
var keywords = ["bill"];
var matching = text.toLowerCase().search([keywords]);
console.log(matching);
// return 34

// Case 3
var text = "Hello, My name is @Steve, I love @Bill, happy new year!";
var keywords = ["steve, bill"];
var matching = text.toLowerCase().search([keywords]);
console.log(matching);
// return -1

// Case 4
var text = "Hello, My name is @Steve, I love @Bill, happy new year!";
var keywords = ["steve", "bill"];
var matching = text.toLowerCase().search([keywords]);
console.log(matching);
// return -1
```

**If there something I missed out to make Case 3 and Case 4 return positive?**

I just want if the text is either **matching with one of the keywords**, it will **return positive**.

But not working at this moment. Helps needed. Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `search()` function that takes an array of strings as a parameter actually defined?

Comment: You can try at http://repl.it 
The search() is defined by default in js, right?

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) reveals that the provided argument to the search method is converted into a regex, resulting in `/steve,bill/` which searches exactly for `"steve,bill"`.

You'll need to provide a proper regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for info. Temporarily I don't have idea the better expression. Can you guide me more? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could instead consider learning how to define a btw. very simple regular expression but well here you go `/steve|bill/i`.

Comment: Mmmm... sorry... I think I'm noob. I still don't get it. Do you mean I can do like this: var matching = text.toLowerCase().search(/[keywords]/i); ???  Thanks again!!

Comment: `text.search(new RegExp(keywords.join("|"),"i"));` if you want it to match if one of the keywords is present.

Comment: Not sure why I still didn't get the desired results... still return negative (-1) :( 

   var text = "Hello, My name is steve, I love bill, happy new year!";      
   var keywords = ["steve, bill"];    
   var matching = text.search(new RegExp(keywords.join("|"),"i"));   
   console.log(matching);    
// -1